Minecraft crashes when RageMode is enabled by pressing the U key
I will say right away, in the logs error does not appear, I use forge version 2859 for minecraft 1.12.2, I wrote a couple of classes one of which is responsible for RageMode, the essence is that the player when turning on RageMode should fly to the nearest entity and inflict it 200 damage, and so once again within 10 seconds, if the player meets obstacles, he must destroy them hitbox. The next class KeyInputHandler, it is responsible for checking the pressing of the key U and then activates RageMode. what is the problem - when entering the game everything is normal, but when you press U the game completely freezes and the only way to turn it off - it is forced to close, looking at the logs there is no record of any errors, just an inscription exit the game with code 0.
Here are the codes:
main file
package daun.aut.utils;

import daun.aut.utils.Handlers.KeyInputHandler;
import daun.aut.recipes.SmeltingRecipes;
import daun.aut.tabs.autTab;
import daun.aut.utils.Handlers.RegistryHandler;
import daun.aut.utils.proxy.CommonProxy;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.Instance;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.SidedProxy;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;



    @Mod(modid = Reference.MODID, name = Reference.NAME, version = Reference.VERSION)
    public class Main
    {
        public static final CreativeTabs autTab = new autTab("autismotab");

        @Instance
        public static Main instance;

        @SidedProxy(modId = Reference.MODID, clientSide= Reference.CLIENT, serverSide = Reference.COMMON)
        public static CommonProxy proxy;

        @EventHandler
        public static void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event)
        {
            RegistryHandler.otherRegistries();
            KeyInputHandler.registerKeyBindings();

        }

        @EventHandler
        public static void Init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
            SmeltingRecipes.init();
            MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(new CustomFog());
            MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(new KeyInputHandler());
        }

        @EventHandler
        public static void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {
        }

    }

RageMode
package daun.aut.utils;

import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.util.DamageSource;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.util.math.Vec3d;
import net.minecraft.world.World;

public class RageMode {

    private EntityPlayer player;
    private World world;
    private long startTime;
    private final long duration = 10 * 20; // 10 seconds (20 ticks per second)
    private final double speed = 1.5; // Speed of movement

    public RageMode(EntityPlayer player) {
        this.player = player;
        this.world = player.world;
        this.startTime = world.getTotalWorldTime();
        activateRage();
    }

    private void activateRage() {
        while (world.getTotalWorldTime() < startTime + duration) {
            EntityLivingBase target = findNearestTarget();
            if (target != null) {
                moveTowards(target);
                attack(target);
                breakObstacles();
            }
        }
    }

    private EntityLivingBase findNearestTarget() {
        // Logic to find the nearest living entity
        return player.world.getNearestAttackablePlayer(player, 50.0, 50.0);
    }

    private void moveTowards(EntityLivingBase target) {
        // Logic to move towards the target entity linearly
        Vec3d playerPos = player.getPositionVector();
        Vec3d targetPos = target.getPositionVector();
        Vec3d direction = targetPos.subtract(playerPos).normalize();
        Vec3d newPos = playerPos.add(direction.scale(speed / 20.0)); // Move by speed per tick

        player.setPositionAndUpdate(newPos.x, newPos.y, newPos.z);
    }

    private void attack(EntityLivingBase target) {
        // Logic to attack the target entity
        target.attackEntityFrom(DamageSource.causePlayerDamage(player), 200.0f);
    }

    private void breakObstacles() {
        // Logic to break obstacles (blocks)
        BlockPos playerPos = player.getPosition();
        Vec3d lookVec = player.getLookVec();
        BlockPos blockPos = playerPos.add(lookVec.x, lookVec.y, lookVec.z); // Convert Vec3d to BlockPos

        if (!world.isAirBlock(blockPos)) {
            world.destroyBlock(blockPos, true);
        }
    }
}


Handler
package daun.aut.utils.Handlers;

import daun.aut.utils.RageMode;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.settings.KeyBinding;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.registry.ClientRegistry;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.InputEvent;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

public class KeyInputHandler {

    private static final KeyBinding rageKey = new KeyBinding("key.ragemode", Keyboard.KEY_U, "key.categories.gameplay");

    public static void registerKeyBindings() {
        ClientRegistry.registerKeyBinding(rageKey);
    }

    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onKeyInput(InputEvent.KeyInputEvent event) {
        if (rageKey.isPressed()) {
            EntityPlayer player = Minecraft.getMinecraft().player;
            if (player != null) {
                new RageMode(player);
            }
        }
    }
}


I need everything to work properly and not crash.

have you tried to debug this yourself? If so: what did you try with what result?

If minecraft is built similar to the convential GUIs like Swing then blocking the event handler thread in onKeyInput() (by looping while (world.getTotalWorldTime() < startTime + duration)) stops all event processing (and probably also all redrawing) - maybe even to the point where world.getTotalWorldTime() no longer advances which would make that loop into an infinite loop.

@ThomasKläger's comment is correct. Input events are handled on the main thread in Minecraft, so blocking in your input handler will freeze the game. In this case your code is blocking indefinitely, causing the game to freeze indefinitely. To understand why you must understand how getTotalWorldTime works. The value returned by that method is only incremented when the world ticks. While blocking the main thread you prevent the world from ticking, preventing getTotalWorldTime from ever incrementing, preventing your code from ever exiting that while loop, maintaining the block indefinitely.
A correct approach to implementing this feature of yours would be to store your RageMode instance on the player or elsewhere and run something like the following every tick (there is a Forge event for this):
Inside RageMode:
public void tick() {
    if (world.getTotalWorldTime() < startTime + duration) {
        EntityLivingBase target = findNearestTarget();
        if (target != null) {
            moveTowards(target);
            attack(target);
            breakObstacles();
        }
    }
}

Inside the event handler:
player.rageMode.tick();

You can then do player.rageMode.startTime = player.world.getTotalWorldTime() or similar instead of new RageMode(player) when you hit the rageKey.
